# Why a Reputation Cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What is the purpose of the daily reputation limit?

The only one reason I could think of would be someone quickly getting an incredulously high reputation and accessing moderation tools to damage the site/content in some way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/59303) on Meta Stack Overflow is probably the definitive one.

There are several reasons including the one you mention. Another is to give you a reason to stop using the site - you've hit the reputation cap, there's no need to keep posting.

Comment: Does the rep cap actually stop people from posting? Especially since more posts means more drive-by up-votes in the future.

Comment: @Thomas - probably not, that part of my comment was slightly tongue in cheek, but it has been mentioned as one of the reasons for having the cap.

Comment: It almost should be one of those meme pictures with a person's face on the multicolored background. "Hit the rep cap? Keep posting, get more rep tomorrow."

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that stackexchange is something like drug... Better than drug

Cap "forces" you to take a break, and do something else. When I reach cap (+ 100 more reputation) I have really no reason to continue posting, as ChrisF said